# pinch zoom doesn't zoom out on move to next fragment page

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I had done pinch zoom with this [polidea Zoomview](https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view/blob/master/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java).I have implemented this pinch zoom code in fragment page.

```
ZoomView zoomView;

//inside onCreateView method

zoomView= new ZoomView(getActivity());
zoomView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

zoomView.addView(gridTable);
zoomView.setRotationY(180);
gridviewlayout.addView(zoomView);
```

[zoomview jar](https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/downloads/detail?name=android-zoom-view.jar&can=2&q=)

Pinch Zoom in and Zoom out was working in gridview table page.But If I zoom-in a page and then scroll to next fragment page.After that when i go back to previous fragment page,the page is still in zoomed state.

What I am trying to do is reset the page in normal state when I move to next fragment page.

I searched a lot of samples.But Everything is related to Imageview.I didn't get any sample for pinch zoom in fragments with layout.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Explain it more, are you using viewpager ?  Is there  a gridview in each fragment?

Comment: With that above code only I can done a pinch zoom.But cant zoom out while move to next fragment page. @mmlooloo

Comment: `scroll to next fragment` how do you implement that? what widget are you using?

Comment: @mmlooloo sorry viewpager is there.I am using viewpager in separate class to connect all three fragment page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add below code to your fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(!isVisibleToUser){
        if(mZoomView != null)mZoomView.zoomTo(1,0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more.I can't get it.please explain with code for atleast one fragment.

Comment: Each fragment must implement `ZoomViewListener` interface, then at the call of   `void onZoomStarted(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);` store those values somewhere then at onResume check those values and if those values are not dummies (-1) call ` zoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y)` with those values.

Comment: Can you create a sample project that has for example 3 fragments with your issue and upload it on github, I will then try to solve it and will email the result back to you in 1 or 2 days .

Comment: I don't know how to upload in github.moreover i am trying to complete this task on today.If you please explain in detail with code for one fragment that's enough for me.

Comment: i will post whole project on github in 5 minutes.

Comment: very much thank you.That code helped me to solve my problem.you really saved my day.For polidea zoomview with fragment layout, I didn't seen any sample in internet.Every sample in google related to imageview.So this answer will be more worth.

Answer (score 1):

check this link...

[ViewPager with detailed fragment lifecycle](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/viewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code/)

that tutorial show to create listener on Pause and Resume Listener for each fragment. So, whenever you changed to other fragments, you can call zoom out in fragment's onPauseListener. This tutorial work for me.

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

override this method :

```
setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
```

this method is invoked each time the position changed. Now you know the is the visible fragment. that means you  know what is not visible too (yeah I'm sherlock). Now you can set zoom value of all other fragments.(comparing previous index and new index  maybe?)

It would be good for you to hold reference to your fragments and implement some methods for them like `reset() or setZoom(float)`

i hope this helps.